# Should I sand textured drywall ceiling patch edges and how?

Tags: ceiling, patching-drywall

After [a little incident](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/244844/148540) I had to get my textured drywall ceiling patched. It is still drying. Should I smooth out those edges after it dries up and before priming and painting? How? I don't think I need to smoothen the entire patch before painting, or do I have to?

Any other advice before painting? I intend to color match and paint just the patch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The texturing looks good! You might want to knock down that hard edge with a putty knife or, maybe better, a fingernail before it fully drys to help blend the edge in with the existing surface. Be sure to let the patch dry fully before priming/painting.

Comment: If you've got to zoom in that close to see a flaw in the ceiling, you've done _very_ well. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: My concern is whether the "edges" will make the patch look like a rectangle after painting it

Answer (score 2):

The texturing looks good! You might want to knock down that hard edge with a putty knife or, maybe better, a finger or rag before it fully drys to help blend the edge in with the existing surface. It doesn't have to be perfect but you really don't want any "sharp" edges like seen in the second photo.

While sanding is an option for after the compound dries, working with it "half dry" is also an option and works well for situations where you have to "knock down" a rough edge or similar. You can scrape at the rough edge or rub it smooth without disturbing the rest of the patch or the existing ceiling textures.

Applying the primer and paint will also help match the texture as it will tend to slightly fill ridges and creases, etc. just enough to make the transition from patch to existing texture blend better.

Answer (score 1):

Since your ceiling has a heavy texture on it, any extensive smoothing will stand out against the texture. The key is to try to keep the patch area as similar as possible to the rest of the ceiling - which is rough. It's more art than anything. If you do any sanding, do it sparingly and on small areas where the texture is off.
Rough edges can be knocked down with a putty knife or a damp sponge even after the spackle has set up - but do it within 24 hours so it isn't hard-set.
Remember, if you don't like it when it's done, it's not hard to redo.
BTW - I assume you dried the area above the ceiling really well before the patch. You don't want to trap moisture inside.

Comment: I am more concerned with the edges of the patch, rather than the smoothness or roughness of the texture inside the edges, though. Yep, inside all dry.